# LinearLayout перестал реагировать на нажатия

Tags: android

У меня есть `layout` файл с `LinearLayout` и тремя `TextView`. `TextView` зависят от состояния `LinearLayout` и, если он нажат, нажаты и `TextView`. Но после "упаковки" `LinearLayout` в адаптере он перестал реагировать на состояние `android:state_pressed="true"` (проверял, не работает именно `LinearLayout`)!

Вот разметка:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:orientation="horizontal"
    android:id="@+id/linearLayout_1"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:background="@color/black" >

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/text_1"
        android:background="@drawable/text_view_background_one"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_weight="8"
        android:layout_marginBottom="0.5dp"
        android:duplicateParentState="true" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/text_2"
        android:background="@drawable/text_view_background_one"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_weight="46"
        android:layout_marginLeft="0.5dp"
        android:layout_marginBottom="0.5dp"
        android:duplicateParentState="true" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/text_3"
        android:background="@drawable/text_view_background_one"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_weight="46"
        android:layout_marginLeft="0.5dp"
        android:layout_marginBottom="0.5dp"
        android:duplicateParentState="true" />
</LinearLayout>
```

Вот `selector` для `TextView`:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<selector xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <item android:drawable="@color/very_light_gray"  android:state_pressed="true" />
    <item android:drawable="@color/white" />
</selector>
```

Вот адаптер (ermak0ff, не злитесь :D):

```
public class CustomListAdapter_Words extends RecyclerView.Adapter<CustomListAdapter_Words.ViewHolder> {
    private static Context mContext;
    private static String[][] mWords;

    public static class ViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder {
        TextView textView_1;
        TextView textView_2;
        TextView textView_3;

        public ViewHolder(View view) {
            super(view);

            this.textView_1  = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.text_1);
            this.textView_2  = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.text_2);
            this.textView_3  = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.text_3);
        }
    }


    public CustomListAdapter_Words(Context context, String[][] words) {
        mContext = context;
        mWords = words;
    }


    @Override
    public ViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(ViewGroup parent, int viewType) {
        View view = LayoutInflater.from(parent.getContext()).inflate(R.layout.row_words_form_1, parent, false);
        ViewHolder myViewHolder = new ViewHolder(view);

        return myViewHolder;
    }


    @Override
    public void onBindViewHolder(ViewHolder holder, final int listPosition) {
        holder.textView_1.setText(mWords[listPosition][0]);
        holder.textView_2.setText(mWords[listPosition][1]);
        holder.textView_3.setText(mWords[listPosition][2]);
    }

    @Override
    public int getItemCount() {
        return mWords.length;
    }
}
```

Почему `LinearLayout` перестал реагировать на нажатия и как это исправить?

Comment: Пробовали каждому ребёнку линеара прставить `android:clickable="false"`?

Comment: @ЮрийСПб, `TextView` не кликабельный. И в `ListView` это работало.